# Chrome Extension: IFrame and listening to clicks within it

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I would like to insert an iframe (frame.html which is part of my extension) into the body of a website and then be able to receive click events for two buttons inside it.

Running into problems with same origin policy, etc.

I'm sure there is a relatively graceful workaround for this, but I'm not having much luck finding it.

Comment: Are you sure you need to use an iframe? If it's not absolutely necessary, you'd avoid headaches like this by simply inserting your html directly into the website.

Comment: The website has a lot of custom CSS which screws up the delicate layout of the content i'm trying to insert. And even if I can get it to look ok now, there's no guarantee that the website's css won't change and screw it up again. Not to keen on playing cat and mouse.

Comment: Honestly, I am mildly certain this is impossible. You might consider resorting to a css "catch-all" that basically removes all possible styles from all of your elements. It seems hacky (and tedious), I know, but it might be your only option in this case.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [message events](http://dev.w3.org/html5/postmsg/) to let the injected iframe window communicate with the content script (take care about [security](http://dev.w3.org/html5/postmsg/#security-postmsg)).

Here is a simple example. The extension injects an IFRAME element into all viewed pages via a content script. The frame contains a page with a button. The button has a click handler which sends a message to the top window. The content script has a listener to messages coming from the iframe which opens an alert displaying the message data.

manifest.json:

```
{
  "name": "Test",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "content_scripts": [ {
    "matches": [ "http://*/*", "https://*/*" ],
    "js": [ "content.js" ],
    "run_at" : "document_end"
  } ]
}
```

content.js:

```
var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");    
iframe.src = chrome.runtime.getURL("iframe.html");
document.body.appendChild(iframe);

addEventListener("message", function(event) {
  if (event.origin + "/" == chrome.runtime.getURL(""))
    alert(event.data);
}, false);
```

iframe.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
  <button id="button">Click me!</button>
  <script>
    document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click", function() {
      top.postMessage("clicked!", "*");
    }, false);
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Looks great, will be trying this shortly.

Comment: chrome.extension.getURL is deprecated, use chrome.runtime.getURL