# I can't gather data from iframe via chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am attempting to make a 5-star rating extension, that makes 5 star's appear on a certain web-page, and gather data on how many user's have rated, and the average rating. I made a .php page with two div tags named 'total' and 'star' - with the total of ratings and the average rating, in which I create an iFrame that opens that page.

When I attempted to grab the data, using

```
 totalrating = $('#getrating').contents().find('#total').html();
```

( getrating = the iframe, total = the div tag with the total of ratings )

it returns null. Is there something wrong I am doing? The page that the 5 stars are going on is a different web-site than mine, so I see no other way than using an iFrame.

Thanks, Alex.

Comment: Maybe this response can help you:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8511752/chrome-extension-iframe-and-listening-to-clicks-within-it/8526096#8526096

Answer (score 0):

The function 'contents()' can get the content only if the iframe exist in the same domain.

maybe this help:

http://pipwerks.com/2008/11/30/iframes-and-cross-domain-security-part-2/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this works:

```
totalrating = $(document.getElementById('getrating').contentDocument).find('#total').html();
```