# Listening for messages coming from an iframe

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, cross-domain, postmessage

I have read some articles on how `window.postMessage` can be used to send messages back and fourth between a page and an `iframe`.

My problem is that I have an `iframe` within the same page that I need to **receive** notifications from. Every so often the `iframe's` DOM gets modified to contain notifications. I want these notifications to propagate out from the `iframe` and to the page itself. How can this be done with `window.postMessage`?

Here is the scenario:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

    ...need to hear events from iframe here...

    <div class="container">
        <iframe src="http://example.com">..(stuff happens in here)..</iframe>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Lets assume I can edit the `iframe's` code to send any events I want, would a custom event work like that or would it fail to propagate through due to the cross-origin policy?

Comment: top.postMessage() goes up.

Comment: This post may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8511752/chrome-extension-iframe-and-listening-to-clicks-within-it

Comment: damn! thanks for that tip, worked like a charm :)